# JFrame replace Java icon with mine

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have looked at other topics but they just answer things I don't understand.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("2D Game/src/img/gameIcon.png"));
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

When I try using `getClass().getResources` it just gives me errors. Anyone help me?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for working examples. The file should be defined somewhere on your class path. `I've looked at other topics but they just answer things I don't understand.` - if there is something about the tutorial you don't understand then tell us what it is. We are not mind readers, we can't guess what you find confusing.

Comment: I read over a comment in another topic, and a guy wrote (Image image) and path/to or something. They didn't really show where to add image. like what folder. I've created a folder in my package, how to link to that? I know the path, but I tried using the path and that wouldn't work

Comment: Read the tutorial. Ask a specific question related to the code you find in the tutorial.

Comment: I did as stated in that tutorial. That tutorial didn't help me at all.   `ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("gameIcon.png");
  frame.setIconImage(icon);`

Comment: *"getClass().getResources it just gives me errors"* - Where errors? What path did you use?

Comment: Have you tried using `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/gameIcon.png")`?

Comment: That didn't work. How do I set the icon image afterwards? I get an error on the last paranthesis. I added a semicolon behind it though, no difference.

Comment: I tried doing this `Image icon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/imgs/gameIcon.png"));
  frame.setIconImage(icon);` but then i get exception errors

Comment: Worked now. I added `frame.setIconImage(getToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/gameIcon.png")));` to it instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/img/gameIcon.png"));
```

This should work. You need to start your path with a `/` .